# what's the name or how to search for this "guiding" process?

Tags: help, tutorial

Platform I'm working on suffer huge coldness after registration. Users get confused and leave, because they have no idea what they can do. To deal with that I want to develop a helping guide to highlight possibilities user has from now on. I want it to dim everything that may distract user and point important thing.

So my question is: How can I search for it in the Internet? Does that approach have a name? I just need a small boost to start with that.

Comment: Google for "lightbox" and "html".. that will give you some good pointers.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean with "huge coldness"?

Comment: I looked for "guided web tutorial" and found this http://usablica.github.io/intro.js/. 
I also looked for "guided tour webpage" and found this article which gives a pretty good list: 
http://www.sitepoint.com/web-tour-instructional-plugins/

Comment: The "guiding thingy" you're referring to is called "onboarding". Searching for that should help you get started. Anyway, this question isn't terribly on-topic..

Comment: On [this Quora post](http://www.quora.com/How-would-I-create-Facebooks-walkthrough-tour-effect-on-my-own-website) you'll find some great links too.

Comment: I've removed your link as we discourage links which are likely to change in the future, breaking the questions.

Answer (score 2):

Search for "feature tour" and you will find a number of good options. Include the language/framework of your platform, and you will likely find a plugin or library that will help you create a feature tour.

Answer (score 1):

You can google for "Onboarding Overlay Screen" or "Onboarding Coach Marks". Try looking at the image results for a quick overview and sample screenshots.

Overlays and coach marks are almost always used together where the overlay is a screen casted over the rest of the screen while maintaining the spotlight on any one of the features. Coach marks are pointers used to point to the "feature-in-spotlight".

You can also google for "onboarding patterns" for general guidelines and techniques related to onboarding.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Android:

You could modify [ShowCaseView](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView) to fit your style in filling the form.

Also, why don't you adopt a CardView and ViewPager to go through the form step by step instead of presenting the User with a ton of data to enter?